# Dereference may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Following snippet produces a lint warning in Android Studio.

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.getString(REDIRECT_KEY) != null) {
        switch (extras.getString(REDIRECT_KEY)) { ...
```

`extras.getString(REDIRECT_KEY)` produces the warning

[image]

> Dereference of 'extras.getString(REDIRECT_KEY)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

But I don't see any scenario where this could happen. Is it a bug in lint checks, that it simply does not recognize my null-checks in the if before? Or do I miss something?

EDIT:
changing the code to following, did remove the warning

```
if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getStringExtra(REDIRECT_KEY) != null){
        switch (getIntent().getStringExtra(REDIRECT_KEY)){
            ...
        }
    }
```

BUT this is only gone because of the way, this lint check works (at least I guess). If I show more infos to this check, it says at one point

> Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts

Looking at the source code of Bundle and of Intent shows:

```
/**
 * Retrieve extended data from the intent.
 *
 * @param name The name of the desired item.
 *
 * @return the value of an item that previously added with putExtra()
 * or null if no String value was found.
 *
 * @see #putExtra(String, String)
 */
public String getStringExtra(String name) {
    return mExtras == null ? null : mExtras.getString(name);
}
```

And BaseBundle

```
/**
 * Returns the value associated with the given key, or null if
 * no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key or a null
 * value is explicitly associated with the key.
 *
 * @param key a String, or null
 * @return a String value, or null
 */
@Nullable
public String getString(@Nullable String key) {
    unparcel();
    final Object o = mMap.get(key);
    try {
        return (String) o;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        typeWarning(key, o, "String", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, BaseBundle sets its return values to @Nullable, while Intent doesn't. So using `getStringExtra` only removes the symoptoms, not the cause. I still guess this is caused by an insufficient lint check, instead of wrong coding on my side. Or does anyone still see a scenario, where a Null pointer can be thrown?

Comment: What line does it give the warning? second or third?

Comment: I think instead of getting String everytime from extras, you should assign it to a variable. Because Your extras may become null on certain situations.

Comment: third line in snippet, or line 80 in image. I am checking for extras == null and for the result of getString() == null. See the If in the second line.

Comment: It seems you should be calling `getStringExtra(REDIRECT_KEY)` instead.

Comment: The thing is, that this never produced a null pointer. There is only the warning that it COULD happen. If the values are really null during runtime, my code still works without errors.

Comment: I think You should do something like: String redirectkey = extras.getString(REDIRECT_KEY);  and then if(redirectKey!=null){} ....

Comment: @Neil thanks for not reading my edits and not understanding, why this is not a duplicate. Same for Jarrod Roberson...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this example taken from [here](https://www.artima.com/underthehood/flowP.html)

```
class Argument {

    public final static int TOMAYTO = 0;
    public final static int TOMAHTO = 1;

    static void argue() {

        int say = TOMAYTO;

        while (true) {

            switch (say) {

            case TOMAYTO:

                say = TOMAHTO;
                break;

            case TOMAHTO:

                say = TOMAYTO;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bytecodes generated by javac for the argue() method are shown below:

```
   0 iconst_0 // Push constant 0 (TOMAYTO)
   1 istore_0 // Pop into local var 0: int say = TOMAYTO;
   2 iload_0 // Push key for switch from local var 0
                          // Perform switch statement: switch (say) {...
                          // Low case value is 0, high case value is 1
                          // Default branch offset will goto 2
   3 tableswitch 0 to 1: default=2
            0: 24 // case 0 (TOMAYTO): goto 24
            1: 29 // case 1 (TOMAHTO): goto 29

                          // Note that the next instruction starts at address 24,
                          // which means that the tableswitch took up 21 bytes
  24 iconst_1 // Push constant 1 (TOMAHTO)
  25 istore_0 // Pop into local var 0: say = TOMAHTO
  26 goto 2 // Branch unconditionally to 2, top of while loop
  29 iconst_0 // Push constant 1 (TOMAYTO)
  30 istore_0 // Pop into local var 0: say = TOMAYTO
  31 goto 2 // Branch unconditionally to 2, top of while loop
```

As you can see for switch statement with String data type a tableswitch is done, and for each case the value passed to switch is compared with the case's value, so what this means is that in your case `extras.getString` can be called multiple times without your previous `if` checks being called, and as such since extras is a bundle there is a chance it might get dereferenced and cause a nullpointer exception.

It's always a good practice to create a local variable instead of doing multiple calls of the method, you can have a look at [this presentation by Jake Wharton](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/eliminating-code-overhead-square-hq-2015) to understand why.

Comment: Thanks, as this is the only answer that really answers my original question "did I miss anything".